# Validate minYear on rule

Tags: cakephp, comparison, rule

This validate rule fail:

```
'rule' => array('comparison', '>=', array('minYear' => date('Y') - 11)),
```

What will a validation rule correct for this?
I need validate minYear >= 2004.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
'rule'    => array('comparison', '>=', date('Y') - 11),
```

Comment: i think it is not right to use date('Y') - 11 as minYear is fixed as >= 2004 so it should be 2004 instead of above calculation. In the above case you need to change the 11 to 12 in next year which will break the rule in next year

Comment: Your suggestion fails:
    Error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'

Comment: you have another idea?